# How to upload array of images and string parameters to server?

Tags: objective-c, client-server, image-uploading

> Upload array of `images` and `string` parameters to server
>   to upload array of images and string. I'm using this approach but only
>   I'm able to upload `single image` that is first one. And other array images are not uploading

```
 [request setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData];
            [request setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:NO];
            [request setTimeoutInterval:30];
            [request setHTTPMethod:action_type];



            NSString *boundary = @"14737809831466499882746641449";
            NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
            [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];



            NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

    if([param isEqualToString:kprofile_pic])
                {

                    //Photo
                    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
                    [body appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"photo[]\"; filename=\"image.png\"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
                    [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: image/png\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
                    [body appendData:[dictionary objectForKey:param]];
                    [body appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
                    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

                }
                else
                {

                [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
                [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition:form-data; name=\"%@\"\r\n\r\n", param] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
                [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [dictionary objectForKey:param]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
                [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

                }


            }


            [request setHTTPBody:body];
```

Answer (score 0):

If array count is fixed then you can append image to body accordingly. But if array count is not fixed or it is dynamic then post the image one by one at server end. Check following:

```
-(void)uploadimage
{
     NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyyMMddHHmmss"];
    NSDate *now = [[NSDate alloc] init];
    NSString *theDate = [dateFormat stringFromDate:now];
    NSLog(@"\n"
          "theDate: |%@| ", theDate);
    UIImage *image = [imagearray objectAtIndex:imagecount];
    imagecount++;


    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.7f)];


    NSURL *dataURL = [NSURL URLWithString:baseurl];

    NSMutableURLRequest *dataRqst = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:dataURL cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:30.0];

    [dataRqst setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    NSString *stringBoundary = @"0xKhTmLbOuNdArY---This_Is_ThE_BoUnDaRyy---pqo";
    NSString *headerBoundary = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",stringBoundary];

    [dataRqst addValue:headerBoundary forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    NSMutableData *postBody = [NSMutableData data];


    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"image\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png",theDate]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[@"Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:imageData];
    [postBody appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [dataRqst setHTTPBody:postBody];

    NSHTTPURLResponse* response =[[NSHTTPURLResponse alloc] init];
    NSError* error = nil ;
    NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:dataRqst delegate:self];

   }

#pragma mark NSURLConnection Delegate Methods

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    self.receiveData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    [self.receiveData appendData:data];

    NSError* error;
    NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                         options:kNilOptions
                                                           error:&error];
    NSLog(@"json..%@",json);
    if (imagecount <[imagearray count]) {
        [self uploadimage];
    }
    else
    {

                UIAlertView *alert=  [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil
                                                                message:@"Data uploaded successfully"
                                                               delegate:nil
                                                      cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                                      otherButtonTitles:nil, nil] ;
                [alert show];
    }

}

- (NSCachedURLResponse *)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection
                  willCacheResponse:(NSCachedURLResponse*)cachedResponse {
    return nil;
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didSendBodyData:(NSInteger)bytesWritten totalBytesWritten:(NSInteger)totalBytesWritten totalBytesExpectedToWrite:(NSInteger)totalBytesExpectedToWrite
{
}
```

Comment: Take one int, suppose int imagecount =0 at the start; Then call [self uploadimage]; And then check - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data In this method, we are checking if image count becomes equal to array count.

Comment: but u r appending imageData where is [uploadimage]

Comment: i want to send in one request

Comment: in one request all array images

Comment: @salmansiddiqui In your case count of image array is fixed or not?

Comment: with my above code i m able to upload but only one image that is first

Comment: ya its above i have shared

Comment: @salmansiddiqui paste your code here and give me generated link

Comment: how can i generate link..??

Comment: ya i have not implemented but i have gone through it in this array of images logic m not getting

Answer (score 0):

```
#import "tesstt.h"
#import "HttpRequest.h"
@interface tesstt ()
{
    int imagecount;
}
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSMutableData *receiveData;
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSMutableArray *imagearray;

@end

@implementation tesstt

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

-(IBAction)submit:(id)sender
{
    imagecount = 0;
    [self uploadimage];
}
-(void)uploadimage
{
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyyMMddHHmmss"];
    NSDate *now = [[NSDate alloc] init];
    NSString *theDate = [dateFormat stringFromDate:now];
    NSLog(@"\n"
          "theDate: |%@| ", theDate);
    UIImage *image = [self.imagearray objectAtIndex:imagecount];
    imagecount++;


    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.7f)];

    NSString *baseurl = @"";

    NSURL *dataURL = [NSURL URLWithString:baseurl];

    NSMutableURLRequest *dataRqst = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:dataURL cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:30.0];

    [dataRqst setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    NSString *stringBoundary = @"0xKhTmLbOuNdArY---This_Is_ThE_BoUnDaRyy---pqo";
    NSString *headerBoundary = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",stringBoundary];

    [dataRqst addValue:headerBoundary forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    NSMutableData *postBody = [NSMutableData data];


    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"image\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png",theDate]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[@"Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:imageData];
    [postBody appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [dataRqst setHTTPBody:postBody];

    NSHTTPURLResponse* response =[[NSHTTPURLResponse alloc] init];
    NSError* error = nil ;
    NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:dataRqst delegate:self];

}

#pragma mark NSURLConnection Delegate Methods

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    self.receiveData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    [self.receiveData appendData:data];

    NSError* error;
    NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                         options:kNilOptions
                                                           error:&error];
    NSLog(@"json..%@",json);
    if (imagecount <[self.imagearray count]) {
        [self uploadimage];
    }
    else
    {

        UIAlertView *alert=  [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil
                                                        message:@"Data uploaded successfully"
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil, nil] ;
        [alert show];
    }

}

- (NSCachedURLResponse *)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection
                  willCacheResponse:(NSCachedURLResponse*)cachedResponse {
    return nil;
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didSendBodyData:(NSInteger)bytesWritten totalBytesWritten:(NSInteger)totalBytesWritten totalBytesExpectedToWrite:(NSInteger)totalBytesExpectedToWrite
{
}
@end
```

Comment: i have array of images and i want to sent to a service on one click, is ur code for passing images on one click or one by one? @Minkle Garg